# HTTP Status Code 405 - Method not Allowed error on sending POST request from postman

Tags: post, postman, http-status-code-405, http-verbs

I am trying to send a **POST** request to PROD server to fetch the response using the API I had created. It is working on my local and non-PROD environments. However, on sending request to PROD it is giving me 405 Error.[image: Error Screenshot:]

Had put in the token required from PROD for authorization too. Also, tried with not providing the date as it is the optional parameter. However, same error getting in response.

Request URL: https://PROD_baseUrl/api/controller/method_name/(optional_date_parameter)

Error Text:
405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

Previously I had sent the same request with change of baseURL to my localhost and non-PROD environment where the request was fetching the response correctly. However, on sending the same request to PROD environment getting the mentioned error.

If possible, can anyone please explain why this error is coming and how I can resolve this error as this is affecting my work and costing me financially.